# What Layout Should I Use for This Project (Java)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I am making a platformer game for a project for class and need to have a chicken character jump on some platforms. I have a start screen and a button, and when the button is clicked, it will change the frame to the first level. When I add the chicken character to the frame as well as the background image, all I can see is the background image. Should I be using a different layout or is there something else I can do. This is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {
        public Main(){

            //Creates Chicken Character
            final JLabel chicken = new JLabel(" ");
            ImageIcon chick1 = new ImageIcon("chicken.gif");
            ImageIcon chick2 = new ImageIcon("chicken2.gif");
            chicken.setIcon(chick1);

            //Sets Chicken Location
            chicken.setLocation(1, 1);

            //Creates Title Image 
            JLabel title = new JLabel(" ");
            ImageIcon tl = new ImageIcon("title.gif");
            title.setIcon(tl);

            //Creates Start Image
            final JButton start = new JButton("");
            ImageIcon st = new ImageIcon("start.gif");
            start.setIcon(st);

            //Creates Options Image
            JButton options = new JButton("");
            ImageIcon opt = new ImageIcon("options.gif");
            options.setIcon(opt);
            options.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            //Creates label for level 0 background image
            JLabel background = new JLabel(" ");
            ImageIcon back = new ImageIcon("level0.gif");
            background.setIcon(back);



            //Creates a panel for level 0
            final JPanel p5 = new JPanel();
            chicken.setLocation(1, 1);
            p5.add(background);

            //Create first frame for "Start" button
            final JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
            p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
            p1.add(start, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            //Create second panel for title label
            final JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
            p2.add(title, BorderLayout.WEST);

            //Create third panel for "Options" button
            final JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
            p3.add(options, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            //Creates fourth panel to organize all other primary
            final JPanel p4 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            p4.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
            p4.add(p1, BorderLayout.WEST);
            p4.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            p4.add(p3, BorderLayout.EAST);


            //When button is clicked, it changes the level
            start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if(start.isEnabled()) {
                        remove(p4);
                        add(new ContentPanel());
                        add(chicken);
                        chicken.setLocation(100, 100);
                        setSize(1440, 500);
                        setLocale(null);
                        chicken.isOpaque();
                        validate();
                    }
                    else {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            });

            //Adds fourth panel to frame
            add(p4, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

        public static void main(String arg[]) {
            Main frame = new Main();

            //Finds screen size of monitor
            Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

            //Creates the frame
            frame.setTitle("Cockadoodle Duty: Awakening");
            frame.setSize(screenSize);
            frame.setLocale(null); 
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            String background = "#000000";
            frame.setBackground(Color.decode(background));
        }
    }

    class ContentPanel extends JPanel{
          Image bgimage = null;

          ContentPanel() {
            MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(this);
            bgimage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("level0.gif");
            mt.addImage(bgimage, 0);
            try {
              mt.waitForAll();
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }

          protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            int imwidth = bgimage.getWidth(null);
            int imheight = bgimage.getHeight(null);
            g.drawImage(bgimage, 1, 1, null);
          }
        }
```

Comment: *"Should I be using a different layout or is there something else I can do."*  I think this is a case for [custom painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) the entire game area in a `JPanel` or `BufferedImage`.

Comment: I think JavaFx is much convenient for this development.
See [this](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835)

Answer (score 0):

Note: It's been a while since I used the Graphics API

**Quick Answer:**

You need to draw everything in your paintComponent method.   Your drawing routine should check the state of all game objects and draw them accordingly.   Right now the panel is drawing the background image - that's it.  Add your chicken image the same way you added your bgImage.

**Some more things to consider:**

If you experience screen flicker look into Double Buffering.

Not to overwhelm you but you might want to do some light reading on game coding. Get a general idea on how to code your game loop and what happens each time the loop is executed.

Since you are using an OO language you should also probably make a Chicken class.

```
public class Chicken {

   private int x;
   private int y;
   private Image chickenSprtie;

   //add get / set for access

}
```

Or even a general Super Class - Sprite with int x, int y. Or even a "Drawable" interface to forces all your drawable game objects to have common methods....